# Certain Steam games not launching (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam

I recently built a new PC and installed Ubuntu 22.04.03, currently running Nvidia 525 as the video driver. Some games such as Darkest Dungeon and Space Haven work flawlessly, while others such as Stellaris and Crysis fail to even launch. Click the Play button, and it will turn blue for a split second as if it's trying to launch, but then revert to green. No crash report, no error message, nothing.

It's been several years since I've dabbled with Linux, so I'm still a newbie, but I'm determined to see this through. Where should I begin in troubleshooting these games? And please let me know what other information is needed, plus how to access it.

- System specs:
- Mobo: MSI GEN3 ATX B550
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600x 6core x12
- GPU: MSI Nvidia RTX 3060x
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64-bit
- GNOME Version: 42.9

Comment: There are only a *small* portion of games that're compatible with Steam's compatibility layer for Linux.  Stellaris not running from Steam means you should open a support ticket with Steam/Stellaris support because it has a Linux version.  Crysis has different reports about problems and support on it.

Comment: I see. I'm not too well versed, although I did recently manage (read: blunder) to solve the Nvidia 535 issue on my own, so there's that. If I need further clarification on specific Ubuntu issues (such as finding things) or general guidance, is this the place to ask? I never feel like I'm in the right place for this sort of thing. Either way, opening a support ticket with both Steam and Paradox now. Thank you.

Comment: You could try the workarounds mentioned at https://www.protondb.com/app/281990 and https://www.protondb.com/app/17300